# CRM2011 UR16 Pre and Post upgrade guidelines

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am planning to upgrade CRM2011 on-premise server to UR16. Currently, it is running on UR13. 
Before pushing UR16 what testing would you recommend that I should perform?

Could you possibly tell me the differences between the 2 rollups / provide me some guidance on what I should look for to test? There must be Pre and Post upgrade checklist items and some guidelines of what features should I test before applying UR16.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UR 14 changes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2849744

UR 15 changes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2843571

UR 16 changes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872369

- your friendly neighborhood Google Proxy :)

Comment: Thanks but I actually meant that what features of CRM should I test before applying UR16. I want to make sure that none of CRM feature breaks after the update. Should I instruct users to test everything (Entities, Reports, Marketing modules, Sales modules, etc) before and after update? What is the best practice regarding this?

Comment: That's always a good idea, of course. Best practice is dependent on your own situation, as always. If you have lots of customizations, I would suggest reading through each UR change log and looking for things that might affect your customizations. The change logs also sometimes mention new features or settings that you can use. If you haven't changed something from the out-of-the-box state, then you generally shouldn't have to worry about any changes or fixes made to it by the UR.